# Show that $T_1=T_2S$ if $R(T_1)=R(T_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T_1,T_2 \in L(V,W)$. Prove that
if $\operatorname{range}(T_1) = \operatorname{range}(T_2)$, then there exists an invertible operator $S \in L(V,V)$ such that $T_1 = T_2S$.

Attempt: If $V$ is finite-dimensional the problem can be solved by taking basis for $V$, $N(T_1)$ and $N(T_2)$. But since the dimension of $V$ is not mentioned, how can the problem be solved when $\dim(V)$ is infinite? That's where I'm struggling.

Any help on the latter case would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please tell me, is this a book question? if yes then which book?

Comment: @PNDas No, I guess it is not. At least I don't know if it is. But a similiar question with the difference that $V$ is finite-dimensional instead of $W$ is in Axel Sheldon's Linear Algebra Done Right.

Comment: @Farhad Then where did you come across this problem?

Comment: @Farhad Are you familiar with "quotient spaces"?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is as follows: with the assumption of Zorn's lemma (or equivalently the axiom of choice), we can assume that $\ker(T_j)$ has a basis (for $j=1,2$), and that this basis may be extended to produce a basis of $V$. Let $\mathcal K_j = (u^j_k)_{k \in \alpha_j}$ denote a basis for the kernel of $T_j$ with $\alpha_j$ denoting an associated index set. Similarly, let $\mathcal B_j = (v^j_k)_{k \in \beta_j}$ denote a set of vectors that can be added to $\mathcal K_j$ to produce a basis $\mathcal B_j \cup \mathcal K_j$ of $V$.

- Argue that the vectors $(T_j v^j_k)_{k \in \beta _j}$ must form a basis of the range of $T_j$, and so $\beta_j$ must be finite. In particular, we can take $\beta_j = \{1,\dots,r\}$ without loss of generality.
- Define $Q_j = \operatorname{span}\{v_1^j,\dots,v_d^j\}$ and $R = \operatorname{range}(T_1) = \operatorname{range}(T_2)$. Argue that the maps $T_j|_{Q_j} : Q_j \to R$ are invertible (for $j=1,2$) ($T|_Q$ denotes the restriction of $T$ to $Q$).
- Define $\bar S:Q_1 \to Q_2$ by $\bar S = [T_2|_{Q_2}]^{-1}T_1|_{Q_2}$. Verify that $T_2|_{Q_2}\bar S = T_1|_{Q_1}$.
- To define $S$, extend the definition of $\bar S$ to a map on $V$ that is zero for all elements in $\ker(T_1)$. Equivalently, define $S$ on the basis elements with
  $$
  S(v^1_k) = \bar S(v^1_k) \quad k= 1,\dots,d, \qquad 
  S(u^j_k) = 0 \quad k \in I_1.
  $$
  Because we have $T_2S(v) = T_1(v)$ for all elements $v$ from our basis $\mathcal B_1 \cup \mathcal K_1$, we have $T_2 S = T_1$ as desired.